# PHP code to validate that the user filled out atleast 1 field

Tags: php, forum

I have a forum where the user can choose which column he or she would like to fill in.

I want to not require each box, but only require that he or she fills out one of the boxes.

Here is a picture of what the forum looks like:
[image]

They can choose to enter information into "Sidewalks and non-roadway areas," or "Parking (no meters)." It is not required to fill all the fields, but just one.

My code seems to work, except it won't spit out the error if the user does not fill out a field. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$var_all = FALSE;        // all variable

     // Fees Validation
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['sidewalk_days_close'])) {
        $var_sidewalk_days_closed = TRUE;
            $var_all = TRUE;
        $fee_SDC = trim($_POST['sidewalk_days_close']);
        }
    if (isset($_POST['parking_noMeters_spaces'])) {
        $var_parking_noMeters_spaces = TRUE;
        $var_all = TRUE;
        $fee_PNMS = trim($_POST['parking_noMeters_spaces']);
        }
    if (isset($_POST['parking_noMeters_days'])) {
        $var_parking_noMeters_days = TRUE;
        $var_all = TRUE;
        $fee_PNMD = trim($_POST['parking_noMeters_days']);
        }
    if (isset($_POST['parking_Meters_spaces'])) {
        $var_parking_meters_with_spaces = TRUE;
        $var_all = TRUE;
        $fee_PMS = trim($_POST['parking_Meters_spaces']);
        }
    if (isset($_POST['parking_Meters_days'])) {
        $var_parking_meters_days = TRUE;
        $var_all = TRUE;
        $fee_PMD = trim($_POST['parking_Meters_days']);
        }
    if (isset($_POST['vehicle_lane_close'])) {
        $var_vehicle_lane_close = TRUE;
        $var_all = TRUE;
        $fee_VLC = trim($_POST['vehicle_lane_close']);
        }
    if (isset($_POST['alley_closure'])) {
        $var_alley_closure = TRUE;
        $var_all = TRUE;
        $fee_AC = trim($_POST['alley_closure']); 
        }
 }

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{ 
    if($var_all == FALSE)
    {
        $problem = TRUE;
        print '<div id="fee_error">Please fill in one of the fields below</div>';
    }
    else
    {
        print 'this is text';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the corrected code

```
<?php

$var_all = FALSE;        // all variable

// Fees Validation
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    if (isset($_POST['sidewalk_days_close']))
    {
        $var_sidewalk_days_closed = TRUE;
        $var_all = TRUE;
        $fee_SDC = trim($_POST['sidewalk_days_close']);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['parking_noMeters_spaces']))
    {
        $var_parking_noMeters_spaces = TRUE;
        $var_all = TRUE;
        $fee_PNMS = trim($_POST['parking_noMeters_spaces']);
    }

    if($var_all == FALSE)
    {
        $problem = TRUE;
        print '<div id="fee_error">Please fill in one of the fields below</div>';
    }
    else
    {
        print 'this is text';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Here is the error I am getting with the modified code you supplied me with: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\row_application\index.php on line 386
Line 386 is this: if($_POST[$var_all] == FALSE) {

Comment: Thanks for notifying. I've edit the answer now. Please check and accept it as the answer if it works

Comment: Alright, now that fix gets rid of the error, but now if the forum is empty, their is no error displayed and it just acts as if the forum was filled out properly.

Comment: I created a form and tried running the code. It works for me. I guess there is a problem in some other part of your code. Try
echo $_POST['parking_noMeters_spaces'] and echo $_POST['sidewalk_days_close'] to leave the form to check if these variables are are getting value from somewhere else.

Comment: I did that, and it returned nothing. Take a look at my code now--I have added everything I have in my PHP that modifies the code. And again, thank you for helping me with this. It helps SO much.

Comment: Everything is correct, it runs perfectly when I try here. Try http://pastebin.com/j5Z6sTUM to debug and check where things are going wrong with you

Comment: It is something on my end. I'll continue to troubleshoot  my issue and try to fix it. Thanks again dude!

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
$var_all = FALSE;       // all variable
```

but you are checking for:

```
 if(isset($_POST[$var_all]) == FALSE) {
```

$var_all will contain either TRUE or FALSE, which won't be in your POST data. I assume that this isn't what you wanted to do. Try checking for the correct field you got in your form

Comment: What would you do to fix this? Sorry I am very new to PHP

Comment: Change if(isset($_POST[$var_all]) == FALSE) to if($var_all == FALSE), and you're good to go

Comment: That got rid of the error, but now the error will not display when the forum is empty. btw--I one upped your response because you explained WHY it wasn't working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You use `<?php` and `?>` tags inside of your PHP-code. Remove them.

Comment: I updated the code. Thanks! Sorry, I just copied and pasted from my code and what I displayed up top was cut from two different parts of my body